# After upgrading to mui v5 emotion-cache.browser.esm.js:288 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , stylis__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.middleware) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, upgrade, emotion

[Browser console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWezJ.png)

```
emotion-cache.browser.esm.js:288 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , stylis__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.middleware) is not a function
    at createCache (emotion-cache.browser.esm.js:288:32)
    at Module.../../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js (emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js:18:64)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.../../node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/StyledEngineProvider/StyledEngineProvider.js (GlobalStyles.js:23:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../src/business.tsx (utils.js:349:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (unsupportedIterableToArray.js:9:1)
    at unsupportedIterableToArray.js:9:1
    at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:36:1)
```

After upgrading to mui v5 I am getting the above error. I am using the yarn workspaces and the dependencies are this

I am generating the react build using webpack and injecting that in Django templates.

I am rendering the App like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  Theme,
  StyledEngineProvider,
} from '@mui/material/styles';

import App from './business/App';
import theme from 'business/common/theme/theme';

declare module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question looks fine, but a couple of pointers.  Be sure to simplify your question title as much as possible.  Think about if you were to search for this answer, what would you type into your search engine?  Also, a helpful description of your image would be best, instead of the default text.  Lastly, for readability your pasted error message should be placed in a code block ( ``` ).  Even though it is not code, this will monospace the font and make it easier to dissect by the community.